# Picklist Formula Sum Question

Tags: apex, formula, picklist

I have created the above formula to accomplish a sum of 20 number value picklists and it came out to 6,233 characters. As you all know, the compile limit is 5000. What can I do to circumvent this?

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Form__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Form__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Contract_Language__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Contract_Language__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_License_Grant__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_License_Grant__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Content_Options__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Content_Options__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Exclusivity__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Exclusivity__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Term__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Term__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Termination__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Termination__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Pricing_for_Multiyear__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Pricing_for_Multiyear__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Payment_Terms__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Payment_Terms__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Invoicing__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Invoicing__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Service_Level_Agreement__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Service_Level_Agreement__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Rep_Warranty__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Rep_Warranty__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Limitation_of_Liability__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Limitation_of_Liability__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Indemnity_Hold_Harmless__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Indemnity_Hold_Harmless__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Assignment__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Assignment__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Code_App_Ownership__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Code_App_Ownership__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Data_Ownership_if_SVU__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Data_Ownership_if_SVU__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Change_of_Control__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Change_of_Control__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Choice_of_Law_Venue__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Choice_of_Law_Venue__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Insurance_Obligations__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Insurance_Obligations__c)))
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's your goal: to obtain a record count of each picklist value or assign points to each value for the picklists?

Comment: It was to get a sum of all the numerical values within the picklist.

Comment: Ah, I see.   It seems like this would be much simpler if you swith these to numeric Integer fields and restric values with validation rules.  You can add help text to guide the user.    Then your formula would be Field1___c + Field2__c  + Field3__c + etc.    This assumes your don't have a UI requirment for picklist values to be used.

Comment: Wouldn't this be too many Validation Rules on a Contract Record to accomplish this small goal? Also, we'd prefer a more "leading" solution.

Comment: That makes sense, then.   The limit on validation rules is between 20 and 500 depending on your edition.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from clarifying comment from James, I have a lame solution! Replace Contract_Rating in all of the fields to "CR", there is really no need for such lengthy field names! =)

Comment: this is genius!

Comment: Not lame at all!

Comment: Didn't work, still too long. 6217 compiled.

Comment: Any other advice?

Comment: Something is not right with the math here, my Msword character counter gave 2069 at the beginning and 1628 after the replacement. Which gave ~20% decrease, which in your case should have dropped the char.count  to 4980 or so, not 16 =0

Comment: It didn't, unfortunately. I ended up using a workflow and field update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the formula approach isn't going to work. I'd suggest using a trigger:

```
trigger UpdateCount on ***NameOfYourObject*** (before insert, before update) {

    if (trigger.isbefore){
        if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate){
            UpdateCount.updateCount(trigger.new);
        }
    }

}


public class UpdateCount{

    public static final list<String> FieldsToSum = new list<String>{
        'CR_Form__c',
        'CR_Contract_Language__c',
        'CR_License_Grant__c',
        'CR_Content_Options__c',
        'CR_Exclusivity__c',
        'CR_Term__c',
        'CR_Termination__c',
        'CR_Pricing_for_Multiyear__c',
        'CR_Payment_Terms__c',
        'CR_Invoicing__c',
        'CR_Service_Level_Agreement__c',
        'CR_Rep_Warranty__c',
        'CR_Limitation_of_Liability__c',
        'CR_Indemnity_Hold_Harmless__c',
        'CR_Assignment__c',
        'CR_Code_App_Ownership__c',
        'CR_Data_Ownership_if_SVU__c',
        'CR_Change_of_Control__c',
        'CR_Choice_of_Law_Venue__c',
        'CR_Insurance_Obligations__c'
    };

    public static void updateCount(list<***NameOfYourObject***> objs){

        for(***NameOfYourObject*** obj : objs){
            obj.Sum_Field__c = 0;  // Note: you will need to create this new field to store the sum of your other fields.
            for(String s : FieldsToSum){
                Integer FieldValue = obj.get(s) != NULL ? Integer.valueOf(obj.get(s)) : 0;
                obj.Sum_Field__c += FieldValue;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the `BLANKVALUE` function?

i.e.

```
VALUE(BLANKVALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Form__c), "0")) + 
VALUE(BLANKVALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Contract_Language__c), "0")) + 
.....
VALUE(BLANKVALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Insurance_Obligations__c), "0"))
```

Let us know if this drops the characters used by enough.

Having said that, I think you're better off changing the fields to be numeric fields anyway. (as per James' comment)

Comment: Changing all of the picklists to numerical fields sounds great from the developer's perspective, but I doubt the users would appreciate it. There would be a lot of numerical codes that they have to keep track of, and it would likely lead to more errors in data entry.

Comment: I guess I made the assumption that the numbers all have similar meanings.  i.e. 1 - low, 2 - medium, 3 - high.  Given they appear to be rating fields, I'd assume there is already ambiguity over which rating means what.  Is 1 good or bad, high or low?  It's a problem that picklists don't solve in the current form.

Comment: If you add a translation to the picklist, you could have text displayed instead of the numbers: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83139/using-custom-label-in-custom-formula-fields/83649#83649

Comment: Ooh, that's nice.

Comment: Thanks. Salesforce has it hidden away, but it's really useful once you know about it.

Comment: I ended up using a workflow and field update.